# Can't pass parameter from jQuery to stored procedure

Tags: jquery, wcf, parameters

I am trying to pass parameters to WCF service and from WCF service to stored procedure, but nothing is going to stored procedure.. value to other parameters in service are getting assign

```
function CallWcfService() {
       // alert("CallWcfServicexxxx");
        jQuery.ajax
        (
         {

             type: Type,
             url: Url,
             data: parameters,
             contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
             dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
             cache: "false",
             crossDomain: true,   //Same result if i remove this line
             processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
             success: function (msg) {
                 ServiceSucceeded(msg);
             },
             error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
         }
       );
}

function ServiceFailed(result) {
        alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
        Type = null; Url = null; Data = null; ContentType = null; DataType = null; ProcessData = null; parameters = null;
}

function callService() {
        DataType = "json";
        Type = "GET";
        var par = 4;
        parameters = null;
        Url = "http://192.168.2.42/CWSERVERWCF/bedtypemasterService.svc/GetBedTypeList?callback=?";
        parameters = "{'strErrMsg':'1'},{'chrErrFlg':'A'},{'pcompanycode':'0'},{'pdiv':'1'},{'ploc':'1'}";
        // alert(parameters);
        ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        ProcessData = true;
        //alert("sssssasasadsds");
        CallWcfService();
}
```

Comment: _"value to other parameters in service are getting assign"_ - Are you saying the values (or some values) do reach at least as far as the server-side code?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the parameters to  CallWcfService()

```
CallWcfService(Type,Url,parameters,...);
```

Comment: sorry mrida i didnt get get u

Comment: parameters are getting assign to wcf service variables because i am returning strErrMsg and chrErrFlg from service

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice that your variables are global.

Comment: Yes variables are global if you are talking about jquery variables..just I have not mentioned full code